# How does the length of sources in a srcset attribute affect performance

Tags: html, image, srcset

I have an image service. Can I simply provide sources for every step of 50 from 50 to 2000. Would 40 sources affect browser performance, not considering document transfer sizes. Consider I have a page with 200 lazy images.

Simply, does browser performance vary from this:

```
<img srcset="/500/img.jpg 500w, /1000/img.jpg 1000w, /2000/img.jpg 2000w" />
```

To this:

```
<img srcset="/50/img.jpg 50w, /100/img.jpg 100w, /150/img.jpg 150w …" />
```